# Listen to devicemotion on document

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any chance to listen to `devicemotion` event on document instead of window?
And use:

```
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', this);
```

instead of:

```
document.addEventListener('devicemotion', this);
```

Comment: Second argument must be `handler`... a function expression..

Comment: 2  Rayon Dabre
by default, if you set "this" as callback, it refers to handleEvent method in class

Answer (score 0):

first think the code `window.addEventListener('devicemotion', this);` is incorrect. it should `window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(){},false);`

having say that the document object is a sub object of window (a.k.a. window.document) there for if you use `document.addEventListenser` is just like bind it to the `window.document.addEventListenser`.

to answer you question there is no difference to bind it to the `window` or `document` the only difference i can think of is if you use the 3rd param in the `addEventListenser`, `useCapture` when you pass true and you then its not *drill down* the event to the children

you can read more in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: devicemotion won't bubble up to window.
I have a SPA that has many documents, but single window.
So I should listen for event only on  current document.
by default, if you set "this" as callback, it refers to handleEvent method in class